# Tkinter using .grid() correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a program that uses .grid(), and I'm having trouble placing two buttons next to each other (vertically).
Here's my code:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, bg='green')
canvas.grid(row=1, column=2)

button1 = Button(root, text="Build Road")
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text="Build Road")
button2.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

and here is the output:
[image: num]

I want the two buttons to be vertically next to each other, like this:

[image: num]

And also, if possible, could I get a full line of these buttons, next to the canvas like this:

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is it possible? If so, please tell me and give me an answer.
Thanks

Comment: The second and third image was edited in MS paint via the first image - not python made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I recommend is to *not* use `grid` in this situation. You can more easily get what you want using `pack`. You clearly have two top-level elements: a canvas on the right and a stack of buttons on the left. So, create a frame for the buttons, and them pack them side-by-side:

```
button_frame = Frame(...)
canvas = Canvas(...)

button_frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

With that, you can now create the button in the frame and lay them out independently of the canvas. Again, `pack` is the best choice since it is designed specifically to lay widgets out in a top-to-bottom and side-to-side manner:

```
button1 = Button(button_frame, ...)
button2 = Button(button_frame, ...)
...
button1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
button2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
...
```

If you really want to use `grid`, then the solution is to count how many buttons you have, and have the canvas span that many rows:

```
canvas.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `rowspan` parameter in `grid` method of canvas to be as the number of rows needed for the button of the desired output (12 in your case):

```
from tkinter import *

buttons = []

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=400, bg='green')
canvas.grid(row=1, rowspan=12, column=2) # Set the rowspan parameter

for i in range(1,13,1):
    button = Button(root, text="Build Road")
    button.grid(row=i, column=0)
    buttons.append(button)

root.mainloop()
```

I also used a list for your buttons, but this is just to demonstrate you how it works. You will propably not need it.

[image]